# Deploy angular playground sandbox app within a shared library codebase

Tags: angular, jenkins, deployment, continuous-deployment, cicd

I have a common shared library which houses buttons, input components, datepicker etc. this library is shared across many other applications. Now the shared library also has a sandbox playground code for developers to see which components the library has. I have a need to deploy the sandbox playground code to an internal server. How do i go about it? Should i have two package.json in the same repo or it would be better to have a separate repo for sandbox playground code. Please let me know my options here.

Below is the structure for both apps: (Image attached below)

```
> projects
      component
      src
          assets
          lib
      package.json
      tsconfig.lib.json
      tsconfig.lib.prod.json
> src
      app
         components
      tsconfig-app.json
      polyfills.ts
> package.json (on root folder)
> tsconfig.json
> Jenkinsfile
> Dockerfile
```

projects/component/src/lib ------> shared library code

src/app ---------------> sandbox playground code

[my-project-structure image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eYpZl.png)

below is the package.json on root level:

```json
{
  "name": "shared-lib",

  "version": "1.0.0",

  "scripts": {

    "ng": "ng",

    "start": "ng serve",

    "build_lib": "ng build component && scss-bundle -e ./projects/component/src/assets/_index.scss -d ./dist/component/assets/main.scss && npm run copy && npm run copy_themes",

    "copy": "cpx \"./projects/component/src/assets/scss/{_variables.scss,_mixins.scss}\" dist/component/assets",

    "copy_themes": "cpx \"./projects/component/src/assets/themes/*\" dist/component/assets/themes",

    "npm_pack": "cd dist/component && npm pack",

    "package": "npm run build_lib && npm run npm_pack",

    "test": "ng test",

    "lint": "ng lint",

    "precommit": "lint-staged",

  },
}
```